# ValueError when try to convert a negative number from csv file to integer

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello i have the csv file below, imported with pandas `data = pd.read_csv("1.csv")`:

```
x1,x2,xb,y
−2,1,1,1
```

I need to convert the negative number (-2) to integer with `int()`, but i get `ValueError`:

```
print(data.iloc[1-1]['x1']) 
> -2 # str

print(int(data.iloc[1-1]['x1']))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '−2`
```

I haven't the error when try to convert positive number:

```
print(data.iloc[1-1]['x2'])
> 1 # str
print(int(data.iloc[1-1]['x2']))
> 1 # int
```

Comment: @sunnytown i don't know what you mean. I add my file in the question. I put the copy of my file in the question

Comment: What you think is a minus sign is probably an *en dash* ('\u2013'). Try this: print(ord(data.iloc[0]['x1'][0])) If the output is 8211 or 8722 then it's either an *en dash* or Unicode minus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that many unicode characters look like a minus sign...

The character that you are showing in your question is U+2212 MINUS SIGN. The character that is used for negative numbers is the ASCII U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS. While the print the same, they **are** different characters. You will have to clean up your data file...

Answer (score 1):

The "−" within "−2" is not a proper minus sign, looks like it but is not the same.

Your print would work like this:

```
print(int(data.iloc[1-1]['x1'].replace("−", "-")))
```

And if you don't want to replace the problematic minus signs with the correct ones one by one, you could do this operation on the whole column.

```
data['x1'] = data['x1'].str.replace("−", "-").astype("int")
```

Comment: How do you think replacing a character with an identical character is going to help?

Comment: @OldBill he is not replacing a character with an identical character, he is replacing one minus with a different minus

Comment: @Cobra it's your comment that does not help. Maybe read the answer carefully and then we can talk

Comment: @Csaba It's impossible to tell from your answer what variants of minus you're using. If you had used Unicode characters ('\uXXXX') that would have made it clear.

Comment: @Cobra If it's impossible to tell the variants then you should not suggest I used identical ones. Instead of investing effort into such claims, you might as well have tried the code in the answer, which solves the specific problem OP is having on converting such negative values to integers. Also, a decent text editor will reveal the difference between the variants, so surely not 'impossible to tell'.